# Unable to get "thumbnailLink" from Google Drive Rest API V3

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to get all images in a google drive folder. I am able to do so but still not getting the **thumbnailLink**.

```
FileList result = mService.files().list()
  .setPageSize(10)
  .setQ("'"+parentFile.getId()+"'" + " in parents and mimeType='image/jpeg' ")
  .setFields("nextPageToken, files(contentHints,description,fileExtension,folderColorRgb,fullFileExtension,
          iconLink,id,kind,md5Checksum,mimeType,name,originalFilename,
          thumbnailLink,videoMediaMetadata,webContentLink,webViewLink)") 
  .execute();
```

Here's the Url that is being hit from the code

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken,%20files(fileExtension,
                   folderColorRgb,iconLink,id,thumbnailLink,kind,mimeType,name,
                   originalFilename,webContentLink,webViewLink)
                   &pageSize=20&q=0B-u5D758kMAgfmh3SnNabDJRaENISXVUR2kwWEw3TWtQSGJpbWhUVTJLaUZyRWtmM3lGTjA
                   %20in%20parents%20and%20mimeType%3Dimage/jpeg%20
```

The Same data parameters (above) yields the thumbnail when use the API Explorer
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive.files.list/m/drive/v3/drive.files.list

Comment: it's worth pasting the URL being hit by the API explorer and spot the difference.

Comment: Have already mentioned that the result by api explorer and code are different.

Comment: that's why I asked to see if the URLs are different

Comment: @pinoyyid Url are exactly same , :) , seems the result for request from android device and for API explorer are different

Comment: that's most unlikely. i suggest you look elsewhere, including the auth header

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Drive APIs reference on SCOPES](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need) refers to *excluding* thumbnails a few times but doesn't help much defining which scope allows thumbnails to be returned.

I upped my scope from
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` to
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and my Node app started retrieving thumbnails for the first time.

This [iOS specific post describing the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38516890/1645942) suggests using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly`

On the basis that we should use the least permissive scope possible I ended up adding the drive.photos.readonly scope to my original scope giving me

`var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly']`

Of course, I'm OT for your platform but the code will be similar I'm sure.

Comment: Ah, I'm now getting 403s for my thumbnails with a ```Rate-limit exceeded That’s all we know``` in the browser. Looks like I can *get* thumbnails but I'll soon be considered a leecher if I do! :-(  https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/picasa/VIW7Gk8Deeg/5GtLiRuXFo0J

Comment: You save may day! Actually add scope drive.photos.readonly works!