# thumbnailLink not returning for anyfile using iOS Google Drive API

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

Ideally l want to display the thumbnails for images stored on a users Google Drive. The code l'm using is:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.pageSize = 50;
query.fields = @"nextPageToken, files(id, name, thumbnailLink, imageMediaMetadata)";
query.q = @"(mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png')";
[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
       didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

Unfortunately even if l remove the mimetype condition (to list ALL files), no GTLDrive record returned contains thumbnailLink. Is there something l'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, l was using the incorrect scope, which meant the API only had access to the Drives metadata. Updating the scope to the following solved my issue:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
```